# Performance : What is the best way to increase the performance of binding multiple comboboxes with same DisplayMemberPath and SelectedValuePath

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

I have 5 combobox in a WPF application.

Below is the code to bind all comboboxes

```
private void BindYears()
{
        cbBeginYear.ItemsSource = listOfYears;
        cbBeginYear.DisplayMemberPath = "YearID";
        cbBeginYear.SelectedValuePath = "YearID";

        cbEnd_Year.ItemsSource = listOfYears;
        cbEnd_Year.DisplayMemberPath = "YearID";
        cbEnd_Year.SelectedValuePath = "YearID";

        cbExactYear.ItemsSource = listOfYears;
        cbExactYear.DisplayMemberPath = "YearID";
        cbExactYear.SelectedValuePath = "YearID";

        cbStart_Year.ItemsSource = listOfYears;
        cbStart_Year.DisplayMemberPath = "YearID";
        cbStart_Year.SelectedValuePath = "YearID";

        cbEndYear.ItemsSource = listOfYears;
        cbEndYear.DisplayMemberPath = "YearID";
        cbEndYear.SelectedValuePath = "YearID";
}
```

Can I do the same in this way and will this below method will help to increase any kind of performance.

```
private void BindYears()
{
            cbEndYear.ItemsSource = cbStart_Year.ItemsSource = cbExactYear.ItemsSource = cbEnd_Year.ItemsSource = cbBeginYear.ItemsSource = listOfYears;
            cbEndYear.DisplayMemberPath = cbStart_Year.DisplayMemberPath = cbExactYear.DisplayMemberPath = cbEnd_Year.DisplayMemberPath = cbBeginYear.DisplayMemberPath = "YearID";
            cbEndYear.SelectedValuePath = cbStart_Year.SelectedValuePath = cbExactYear.SelectedValuePath = cbEnd_Year.SelectedValuePath = cbBeginYear.SelectedValuePath = "YearID";
}
```

Comment: You could measure it?

Comment: I am not sure, my main concern is best practices. 
which is the best way to go from the above two

Comment: Best practice is NOT to do it using C#. Use XAML and use MVVM. As for performance..the best practice is to get it working, then IFF you have perf issue THEN perf tune it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment, I'd probably do it this way:

```
private void BindYears(Combobox box)
{
    box.ItemsSource = listOfYears;
    box.DisplayMemberPath = "YearID";
    box.SelectedValuePath = "YearID";
}

private void BindBoxes()
{
    BindYears(cbBeginYear);
    BindYears(cbEnd_Year);
    BindYears(cbExactYear);
    BindYears(cbStart_Year);
    BindYears(cbEndYear);
}
```

Comment: The OP asked about performance. Given a JITer, HOW is that actually faster than what the OP has written? It might be true that I would "refactor" the code like you IF I had to. But if this is about best practice, then the OP should be using MVVM.